# APEX Sharing stopped working in community

Tags: community, sharing, apex-managed-sharing

We had a small widget that allowed customers to share records that were set to a private sharing model in our community. Everything was rather simple and it would simply allow them to select users that were visible via Sharing Sets and create an __Share record in APEX.

I've been reported recently that an error is thrown but only on the community side of things. Nothing seems to be working where it was working. We are using    **Customer Community Plus** licenses.

The error being thrown is : `System.TypeException: DML operation INSERT not allowed on <Object>__Share` which seemed to indicate access not available on the object. That seems odd because they are able to interact with the object just fine in order to create/edit/delete them.

I looked up the Sharing Model (its private both internally and externally), I looked at the profile and their access and the sharing sets in the community. Like I said, they seem to interact fine with the objects when it comes to seeing the records and their right.

Additionally, standard license users can use the component fine and also share with community users without a problem. They also see the records as expected.

Am I missing an update or something that seem to make it so this doesn't work anymore? Anyone having trouble with this or encountered the same problem?

Comment: Which Object are you trying to share from Community?

Comment: Have you accidentally clicked on Disable External Organization SHaring?
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.securityImplGuide.meta/securityImplGuide/security_owd_external_disable.htm

Comment: @PranayJaiswal if external owd is disabled, it inherits from internal. And in this case OP mentions both are private, so even if external is disabled, it won't have any impact.

Comment: @JayantDas Correct. Its enabled and both are private. Also, I am using this on Custom Objects and used a generic name because there are more than one.

Comment: @P.Lapointe Are you sure this worked before? And if yes, how was it implemented?

Comment: @JayantDas Positive that it worked before. We even changed from the Standard to the Plus licenses for community to enable full licenses like sharing capabilities and were sold on the fact that it was the was the same. I can read the Sharing records as those user and retried them from SOQL queries and they do their job when it comes to sharing. We simply cannot seem to do any DML operation on them as of recently and I've only been made aware yesterday.

Comment: @P.Lapointe I have added some documentation reference as answer. It clearly mentions that Customer Community Plus licenses cannot access `share` object, and that seems to be your case. You will need to address is as mentioned in the documentation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you refer to [Sharing a Record Using Apex](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_bulk_sharing_creating_with_apex.htm) documentation, and within that refer to the section (all the way at the bottom of the page) **Creating Apex Managed Sharing for Customer Community Plus users**, you will find that `Share` objects are **not available** for Customer Community Plus Licenses. The complete text from the documentation is as below (emphasis mine).

You will need to address this situation by taking the approach as mentioned in the documentation (by using `without sharing`).

> **Creating Apex Managed Sharing for Customer Community Plus users**
>
> Customer Community Plus users are previously known as Customer Portal users. **Share objects**, such as AccountShare and ContactShare, **aren’t available to these users**. If you must use share objects as a Customer Community Plus user, consider using a trigger, which operates with the `without sharing` keyword by default. Otherwise, use an inner class with the same keyword to enable the DML operation to run successfully. A separate utility class can also be used to enable this access.
>
> Granting visibility via manual/apex shares written to the share objects is supported but the objects themselves aren't available to Customer Community Plus users. However, other users can add shares that grant access to Customer Community Plus users.

Comment: It seems the without sharing keyword was removed recently as part of a security check. This wasn't caught anywhere and it only resurfaced now. Putting it works fine. Will investigate to find an appropriate way to handle this since Lightning sharing is not a thing yet.

Comment: That's your culprit! Glad you were able to find it real quick.

Comment: What you could do is have a utility (sub)class that is explicitly "without sharing" but only performs specific functions. Make sure to comment/document WHY you are legitimately executing this piece without sharing. The main component controller should always be "with sharing" but it can call the utility to do the DML with elevated privileges. Ideally the "without sharing" utility should also do some checks as to whether it is a legit use case.